# Confused on left joins (simple scenario)

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I understand inner joins but I am confused when it comes to outer joins. 
Table 1 has two rows as shown below:

```
tbl1:
1
1
```

Table 2 has two rows as shown below:

```
tbl2:
1
2
```

Inner join: 2 rows (I understand, 2 rows in `tbl1` are matching with a value in `tbl2`)
Left outer join: will it be 3 rows (All on `tbl1` and common between the two tables)

Comment: Please explain better your example. Use column names and values so other users with the same doubt can understand your question. Also for you to get the right answer you need to ask the right question.

Comment: You should improve and clarify your example, but it looks like in your example you'd get the same result as the inner join.

Comment: It was part of my interview question where i was given two tables as above and was asked to explain the numbers of rows i would get as an output for all the types of joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the table or resultset on the right side of the LEFT OUTER JOIN has matching values then there is no difference between OUTER and INNER JOIN. It is the situation in your example - you get two rows 
for `SELECT * FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.number=tbl2.number`:

```
tbl1.number  tbl2.number
1            1
1            1
```

But you get the same result using `SELECT * FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.number=tbl2.number`.

The difference is on the left side of the LEFT OUTER JOIN - you say I want all rows from `tbl1` regardless on if there is a matching row in `tbl2`.

So if you delete the first row from `tbl2` with `DELETE FROM tbl2 WHERE number = 1` and run the command with INNER JOIN `SELECT * FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.number=tbl2.number` - you get 0 records because there are no matching records in `tbl2`.

And if you then run `SELECT * FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.number=tbl2.number`, you get:

```
tbl1.number  tbl2.number
1            NULL
1            NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, that cleared what i was confused about.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using SQLite:

```
sqlite> create table tbl1(value int);
sqlite> insert into tbl1 values(1);
sqlite> insert into tbl1 values(1);
sqlite> create table tbl2(value int);
sqlite> insert into tbl2 values(1);
sqlite> insert into tbl2 values(2);
```

If `tbl2` is left-joined on to `tbl1`, you'd get two results:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.value = tbl2.value;
1|1
1|1
```

This is because `tbl1` is the "left" table, so every row from `tbl1` will be included, whether or not it has a match in `tbl2`.

If `tbl1` is left-joined on to `tbl2`, you'd get three results:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM tbl2 LEFT JOIN tbl1 ON tbl1.value = tbl2.value;
1|1
1|1
2|
```

This is because:

- Every row from `tbl2` will be included, whether or not there is a match in `tbl1`
- Rows in `tbl2` may match multiple rows in `tbl1`.

In this case, `tbl2` has two rows with matches in `tbl1` plus one row without a match, resulting in three rows total.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, it was helpful in understanding the concept.